# how change font of ToolTip in qt quick controls2?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

I want to change the font family of ToolTip but I got below error

> QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component
>
> qrc:/main.qml:132 Type BookPage unavailable
>
> qrc:/pages/BookPage.qml:41 Type BookItem unavailable
>
> qrc:/pages/BookItem.qml:102 **Cannot assign to non-existent property "font"**

```
ToolButton{
    id: tbtnStatistics

    ToolTip.visible:down
    ToolTip.delay: Qt.styleHints.mousePressAndHoldInterval
    ToolTip.text: "This is Tooltip"
    ToolTip.font.family: "tahoma"
    ToolTip.timeout: 4000

    contentItem: Image {
        fillMode: Image.Pad
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
        source: "../images/statistics.png"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

QML does not support having many levels of nesting so this type of problem is usually observed, it is appropriate to reduce it as shown below:

```
ToolButton{
    id: tbtnStatistics

    ToolTip{
        visible: tbtnStatistics.down
        delay: Qt.styleHints.mousePressAndHoldInterval
        text: "This is Tooltip"
        font.family: "tahoma"
        timeout: 4000
    }

    contentItem: Image {
        fillMode: Image.Pad
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
        source: "../images/statistics.png"
    }
}
```